# Does HDFS create all directories on requested path?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

It seems that if the path contains nested directories e.g. `a/b/c/` then the call to `create` creates all those directories on path ...

```
fileSystem.create(new Path(path), true);
```

.. similar to a call to `File.mkdirs`

Is this a documented feature of HDFS?

Comment: FWIW, The API at http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/hdfs/r0.22.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSClient.html indicates that the creation of parent directories defaults to true. Admitted, this is not the same exact call as invoked from DistributedFileSystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of `FileSystem` API's `create(…)` methods (when used over a `HDFS` implementation, specifically) will send a `create-parent` flag to the server, asking for parents to be automatically created if they do not already exist.

Since FileSystem implementations are different in behavior for each platform, this is, expectedly, not true for local filesystem (`file://` paths) create calls.

The toggle feature is available in the FileContext's [create](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileContext.html#create%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20java.util.EnumSet,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Options.CreateOpts...%29) API, available in Hadoop 2.x onwards, which allows providing an `Options.CreateOptions.donotCreateParent()` option in order to disallow or control this behavior.